# Challenge on ASCII Codes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

My friend shared a challenge puzzle with me but I don't have any idea how to solve it. I believe that it's related to ASCII characters.

[image: Challenge Puzzle]

Comment: Any chance we can get a transcription of the image?

Comment: I don't have transcription of this image

Comment: It seems so. First step would be to convert hex (ASCII) to text. It contains some Morse code.

Comment: ascii is just a system that maps numbers to characters. The numbers can be base 10, base 2, base 16, etc. In this case, it is in base 16 (since it contains letters A-F which are hex digits).

Comment: I have to convert these codes to base 16 right?? could you please help me out...still i am not clear

Comment: They already are base 16 but they can be converted to text. http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/

Comment: for testing purpose can i copy only first row and first column D8 FF only

Comment: The second row is more intelligible

Comment: i have tried this D8 FF it gave this output 44 38 20 46 46

Comment: The second row: 2E 5F 2E 5F 6F 73 65 6D 61 52 64 6E 6D 6F 68 43 becomes "._._osemaRdnmohC"

Comment: Not all of it can be converted this way because some of it is not in the range of printable characters

Comment: WOW thats great..please explain me how did you get that output??/

Comment: Hex numbers to text using that website above. Select it from the dropdown

Comment: this is the first row output ����FB!H'n

Comment: This is for 3rd row                                                                                                              racaetsr_._.

nO

Comment: I believe I have gotten the full solution. If you think it is correct, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: look what I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896434/how-to-go-to-the-next-line-instead-of-printing-n please note the characters they are trying to print!!! 8 months ago

Comment: reddit thread, with the exactly the same image. They came to no better conclusion than we did here https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/d24c6h/hexcode_challenge/

Comment: To whomever flagged/voted for this to be closed as lacking attribution: the [meta consensus](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7221/69582) is that saying a puzzle is from a friend is sufficient for policy

Answer (score 13):

#### Transcription of the grid:

```
00000000 D8 FF E0 FF 10 00 46 42 11 21 01 00 48 00 27 6E
00000010 2E 5F 2E 5F 6F 73 65 6D 61 52 64 6E 6D 6F 68 43
00000020 72 61 63 61 65 74 73 72 5F 2E 5F 2E 0A 0A 6E 4F
00000030 79 6C 61 20 20 6E 6C 69 75 6C 69 73 65 76 6D 20
00000040 6E 69 20 64 69 77 68 74 69 20 6C 6C 73 75 76 69
00000050 20 65 68 74 75 6F 68 67 73 74 63 20 6E 61 62 20
00000060 61 65 20 72 6F 74 73 20 65 65 72 20 61 65 69 6C
00000070 79 74 20 2C 73 41 69 20 6C 6C 73 75 6F 69 20 6E
00000080 6E 6F 65 63 63 20 65 72 74 61 64 65 61 20 65 72
00000090 6E 20 77 6F 72 20 61 65 69 6C 79 74 20 2E 73 49
000000A0 27 6E 20 74 74 69 0A 3F 43 0A 6E 6F 72 67 74 61
000000B0 2C 73 59 20 75 6F 68 20 76 61 20 65 61 6D 65 64
000000C0 69 20 20 74 65 68 65 72 0A 21 4E 0A 77 6F 20 2C
000000D0 65 54 6C 6C 75 20 20 73 62 61 75 6F 20 74 6F 79
000000E0 72 75 66 20 76 61 72 6F 74 69 20 65 61 48 6B 63
000000F0 20 20 20 2D 6F 50 74 73 61 6D 20 6E 65 53 75 63
00000100 69 72 79 74 54 20 61 65 0A 6D 5F 0A 5F 2E 73 2E
00000110 6D 6F 52 65 6E 61 6F 64 43 6D 61 68 61 72 74 63
00000120 FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48
```

#### Left column

> The column on the left is all multiples of 16 in hex numbers from 0 to 288:
>  0, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208, 224, 240, 256, 272, 288

#### Remaining grid

> Translation of the right-side grid (Hex numbers to text):

`[NL]` below represents a "new line" character.

```
����FB!H'n
._._osemaRdnmohC
racaetsr_._.[NL][NL]nO
yla  nliulisevm 
ni diwhti llsuvi
 ehtuohgstc nab 
ae rots eer aeil
yt ,sAi llsuoi n
noecc ertadea er
n wor aeilyt .sI
'n tti[NL]?C[NL]norgta
,sY uoh va eamed
i  teher[NL]!N[NL]wo ,
eTllu  sbauo toy
ruf varoti eaHkc
   -oPtsam neSuc
irytT ae[NL]m_[NL]_.s.
moRenaodCmahartc
����JFIFH
```

> Text is scrambled but only within individual words.
>  
>  `osemaRdnmohC racaetsr`
>  `some Random Characters`
>  
>  `nOyla  nliulisevm ni diwhti llsuvi ehtuohgstc nab ae rots eer aeilyt,`
>  `Only an illusive mind with illusive thoughts can bear to see reality,`
>  
>  `sAi llsuoi nnoecc ertadea ern wor aeilyt.sI 'n tti?`
>  `As illusion once created are now reality. Isn't it?`
>  
>  `Cnorgta,sY uoh va eamed i teher!`
>  `Congrats, You have made it here!`
>  
>  `Nwo,eTllu sbauo toyruf varoti e aHkc`
>  `Now, Tell us about your favorite Hack`
>  
>  `-oPtsam neSuc irytT aem`
>  `- Postman Security Team`
>  
>  `s.moRenaodCmahartc`
>  `some Random Charact...`

### Full answer to the puzzle:

> Only an illusive mind with illusive thoughts can bear to see reality,
>  As illusion once created are now reality. Isn't it?
>  Congrats, You have made it here!
>  Now, Tell us about your favorite Hack
>  - Postman Security Team

Comment: How can we proceed with the below output and what it symbolizes??

Comment: after getting these output how to proceed with this?

Comment: No idea. Since there is some punctuation and spaces. I assume rearranging the text in some way would make it readable. There are websites such as http://boulter.com/anagram/ that can help with finding words in text, but there are so many possibilities.

Comment: sure i will try and get back to you if i get any

Comment: `Y uoh va eamed
i  teher`

=> `You have made it here`

Comment: Within individual *lines*, not individual *words*, right?

Comment: It's individual words as in `yuo => you`, `hvae => have`. All letters are adjacent.

Comment: `bare` should be `bear`.  Unless you're talking about removing one's clothes...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You are right. I wasn't sure how that was spelled.

Comment: Last line is the JPG file header: FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 and like a few more after. Maybe if you reverse order of lines and open as jpg you will gett an image

Comment: 1) The left column is just the offset, like line numbers for a hex editor, not part of the actual data.  2) The scrambling is just every two bytes being swapped.  Because of the vertical lines I guess that, again, this is just due to the display of their hex editor (some can be configured to do this).  3) The first four bytes are (also swapped) the SOI (start of image) and APP0 (metadata) markers for a JPEG image.  So the whole file is probably just a JPEG with this text inserted in the middle.  My guess is that this is for a CTF contest and `_._.someRandomCharacters._._` is the flag.

Comment: The transposition is just a form of endian-swizzling.